# scroll inside the tooltip scrolls the entire page in react @material-ui/core/Tooltip

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, material-ui, tooltip

I have a tooltip created using `@material-ui/core/Tooltip`
`https://codesandbox.io/s/kgccc` which work fine as shown below

[image]

since the content is more, have provide scroll

```
 .tooltip-popup-details{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

when tried to scroll the tool tip by clicking inside the content entire page scroll tried alot to fix it but could not make it basically drag or scroll inside tool tip is not working please help

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the Material UI example and made a fork with a tooltip that has a fixed height and a scrollbar like yours. [Here it is](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gojqk). I can scroll inside the tooltip with my touchpad, and with the scrollbar of the tooltip.

I have added `interactive={true}` on the tooltip, otherwise the tooktip disappears when moving the mouse out of the button that triggers it.

Comment: interactive={true} - that's the key